# HttpContext Username Duplicating across Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, httpcontext, authentication

So I have a problem. I have my own CustomMembership class that i use in virtually all of my MVC applications, and this custom class inherits 'MembershipProvider'.

each app has its own user database and so the user information is rarely replicated across the individual applications, unless people have accounts in each. At any rate, since deploying them, I realize more and more, that the HttpContext is replicating across these applications over the IIS. I have 2 major problems:

1. Someone will sign in as 'user1', yet the HttpContext is returning a username for 'user3'
2. The User context from one application will be in cache or a session, or whatever, and then show up in another application. Eg. I was about to test an application and it gave me an exception when fetching the user roles because the username it was searching for does not exist in this application, but another, and for some reason is being touting as the current context.

This is perplexing, I was wondering if I am missing something or failed to initialize something. Below is a copy of my web config user authentication section.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="HRUpdate.App_Data.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="HRpimEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    <!--<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/"/>-->
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="HRUpdate.App_Data.MyRoleProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Is your CustomMembership class a static class with a static Username member?

Comment: No static class. My Membership class is define as such: 
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider {...}